# Is there an equivalent of vector::reserve() for an std::list?

Tags: c++, list, stl, vector

I have a class that looks like this:

```
typedef std::list<char*> PtrList;
class Foo
{
public:
   void DoStuff();
private:
   PtrList m_list;
   PtrList::iterator m_it;
};
```

The function `DoStuff()` basically adds elements to `m_list` or erases elements from it, finds an iterator to some special element in it and stores it in `m_it`. It is  important to note that each value of `m_it` is used in every following call of `DoStuff()`.

**So what's the problem?**
Everything works, except that profiling shows that the operator `new` is invoked too much due to `list::push_back()` called from `DoStuff()`.

To increase performance I want to preallocate memory for `m_list` in the initialization of `Foo` as I would do if it were an `std::vector`. The problem is that this would introduce new problems such as:

1. Less efficient `insert` and `erase` of elements.
2. `m_it` becomes invalid as soon as the vector is changed from one call to `DoStuff()` to the next. **EDIT:** Alan Stokes suggested to use an index instead of an iterator, solving this issue.

**My solution:** the simplest solution I could think of is to implement a pool of objects that also has a linked-list functionality. This way I get a linked list *and* can preallocate memory for it.

Am I missing something or is it really the simplest solution? I'd rather not "re-invent the wheel", and use a standard solution instead, if it exists.

Any thoughts, workarounds or enlightening comments would be appreciated!

Comment: What exactly are you using those char* for ?

Comment: @ScarletAmaranth Those are pointers to locations in memory, where data packets are stored (I simplified it to char* for the question).

Comment: Have you checked whether it actually performs better if you just use a `vector`? It might well do; fast allocation and good cache behaviour often make up for the insert/delete cost.

Comment: You can specify a custom `Allocator` (the second parameter to the `list` template) and use it to allocate from your pool. You might find `boost::pool` useful.

Comment: @Eitan could you store an index rather than an iterator into the `vector` to avoid the invalidation? (Being careful when inserting and deleting.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you are using wrong the container.

If you want fast push back then don't automatically assume that you need a linked list, a linked list is a slow container, it is basically suitable for reordering.

A better container is a std::deque. A deque is basically a array of arrays. It allocates a block of memory and occupies it when you push back, when it runs out it will allocate another block. This means that it only allocates very infrequently and you do not have to know the size of the container ahead of time for efficiency like std::vector and `reserver`.

Comment: I need a fast `erase` in addition to a fast `push_back`.

Comment: Have you actually benchmarked that `erase` of `std::deque` against that of `std::list`. `std::list` are really very slow in comparison to contiguous storage containers. How larger are your sets.

Comment: Haven't benchmarked it, no. My sets would contain about ~10,000 elements.

Comment: I would string recommend benchmarking it, if you implementation of `std::deque` is able erase from a single block (or it only has to shuffle down the elements in that block) then I would be surprised if it was slower.

Comment: I suspect that `insert` and `erase` would be much faster for `std::list` than for `std::deque`, but that might just as well be compensated by the more efficient allocations of `deque`. I'll give a try too.

Comment: @EitanT I suspect the exact opposite, I think `std::deque` will have much faster `insert` and comparable `erase`. It will also have considerably fast iteration

Comment: PS: how long on average are the string you store in the `std::list`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11483/discussion-between-111111-and-eitant)

Comment: Tried `deque` and it does show a slight improvement in performance by reducing the number of calls to the new operator (probably because I'm inserting in the middle way less than I'm using push_back).

Comment: Bottom line: although your answer doesn't directly answer my question, it does provide a solution to my problem, so I will accept it.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `splice` function in `std::list` to implement a pool. Add a new member variable `PtrList m_Pool`. When you want to add a new object and the pool is not empty, assign the value to the first element in the pool and then splice it into the list. To erase an element, splice it from the list to the pool.

But if you don't care about the order of the elements, then a `deque` can be much faster. If you want to erase an element in the middle, copy the last element onto the element you want to delete, then erase the last element.

Comment: "But if you don't care about the order of the elements, then a deque can be much faster." - `std::deque` is also ordered.

Answer (score 3):

List and vector are completely different in the way they manage objects.

Vector constructs elements in place into a allocated buffer of a given capacity. New allocation happens when the capacity is exhausted.
List allocate elements one by one, each into an individually allocated space.

Vector elements shift when something is inserted / removed, hence, vector indexes and element addresses are not stable.
List element are re-linked when something is inserted / removed, hence, list iterators and elements addresses are stable.

A way to make a list to behave similarly to a vector, is to replace the default allocator (that allocates form the system every time is invoked) with another one the allocates objects in larger chunks, dispatching sub-chunks to the list when it invokes it.
This is not something the standard library provides by default.

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm not talking about standard library itself, maybe there are other "standard" implementations for such purposes. Surely I'm not the first one wanting to preallocate memory for a `std::list`...

Comment: @NicolBolas Some years ago I wrote this: [http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13265/On-heap-fixed-allocation-outside-MFC]: may be it needs some adjustement to fit C++11 style, but it should work!

Comment: @EitanT: "You meant to say ..." ... oops, just fixed! Sorry

Answer (score 3):

My advice is the same as `111111`'s, try switching to `deque` before you write any significant code.

However, to directly answer your question: you could use `std::list` with a custom allocator. It's a bit fiddly, and I'm not going to work through all the details here, but the gist of it is that you write a class that represents the memory allocation strategy for list nodes. The nodes allocated by `list` will be a small implementation-defined amount larger than `char*`, but they will all be the same size, which means you can write an optimized allocator just for that size (a pool of memory blocks rather than a pool of objects), and you can add functions to it that let you reserve whatever space you want in the allocator, at the time you want. Then the list can allocate/free quickly. This saves you needing to re-implement any of the actual `list` functionality.

If you were (for some reason) going to implement a pool of objects with list functionality, then you could start with `boost::intrusive`. That might also be useful when writing your own allocator, for keeping track of your list of free blocks.

Comment: +1: Thanks for your advice. I wanted to conserve time so I wanted to hear other suggestions before I decided to write anything complicated of my own. I followed 111111's suggestion and switched to `deque`. So far it's working for me (mainly because most of my insertions are `push_back`s and not in the middle).

Answer (score 1):

Could potentially use `list::get_allocator().allocate()`. Afaik, default behaviour would be to acquire memory as and when due to the non-contiguous nature of `list`s - hence the lack of `reserve()` - but no major drawbacks with using the `allocator` method occur to me immediately. Provided you have a non-critical section in your program, at the start or whatever, you can at least choose to take the damage at that point.